# Why won't jQTouch work on my localhost?

Tags: jqtouch

I was trying out the jQTouch demos on my localhost. I couldn't get any response after clicking on "Submit". I Googled the problem and only found this [link text](http://code.google.com/p/jqtouch/wiki/OfflineSupport) but it doesn't work.

Comment: any errors in statut bar or in error console ?

Comment: please provide some code

Answer (score 2):

Just remember to add the ajax file(such as ajax_post.php) in the .htaccess file. Cheers!

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|javascript|**ajax_post\.php**|robots\.txt|captcha)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [same-origin policy](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy) prevents localhost AJAX requests since the domains of the request and the response are different. To workaround this, [use the IP Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181927/difference-between-localhost-and-ip-address-in-ajax-request-sending), [disable the policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/chrome-disable-same-origin-policy), or add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header to the response.