# Difference between localhost and IP address in Ajax request sending

Tags: javascript, ajax, request, ip-address, localhost

I have a strange problem with native Ajax request invoking.

I am creating the Ajax object and sending the request like follows:

```
var xmlHttpObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

....

```
xmlHttpObj.open("GET","http://192.168.16.254:8080/ajax/demoExample.html",true);
xmlHttpObj.send();
```

When I access the servlet with the URL something like `http://localhost:8080/ajax...`,
then I am not able to get the response in the client side. But I can see the response in the server side.

Pretty similar way I invoked the request with

```
xmlHttpObj.open("GET","http://localhost:8080/ajax/demoExample.html",true);
```

and my URL is `http://192.168.16.254:8080/ajax...`, then also I am not able to see the response in my client side.

I know the best way to fix the problem.

I can invoke the request with

```
xmlHttpObj.open("GET","../ajax/demoExample.html",true);
xmlHttpObj.send();
```

then I don't have any problem with either localhost or IP address.

But still I think why is the difference between localhost and IP address in ajax requesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's more of a security feature than a problem :

> The [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) prevents a
>   document or script loaded from one
>   origin from getting or setting
>   properties of a document from another
>   origin.

localhost and 192.168.16.254 are considered different origins. The same goes for two hostnames that point to the same address as they could (and probably will) point to a different site/application on the same server. AFAIK the only way around this is to use [`iframe`](http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes) for content or [`JSONP`](http://ajaxian.com/archives/jsonp-json-with-padding) for json. Although in your case relative URLs is the way to go.