# FireBug Lite on IE Capturing localhost Traffic

Tags: firebug, firebug-lite

I am trying to use FireBug Lite on IE to capture localhost traffic but it seems like FireBug Lite is not able to read the traffic on localhost. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [IP address or relative paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181927/difference-between-localhost-and-ip-address-in-ajax-request-sending) instead of `localhost`. The [Same-Origin-Policy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/08/28/explaining-same-origin-policy-part-1-deny-read.aspx) prevents the request, since the name `localhost` does not match the target URL.

**References**

- [Browser Arcana: IP literals in URLs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2014/03/06/browser-arcana-ip-literals-in-urls/)